# Get Jackd to coordinate with ALSA and AudioInjector Octo?

Tags: alsa, raspbian-lite

I am attempting to run the AudioInjector Octo on a Raspberry Pi 4, running the Raspberry Lite OS.

My understanding is that ALSA manages AudioInjector - but that I also need jackd to send audio from my software (SuperCollider) to ALSA.

While ALSA seems to read the AudioInjector without trouble, I seemingly cannot get jackd to boot. I am new to Raspberry Pi, so there may be many things I have not yet tried.

Namely, the following line of code causes my terminal prompt to freeze:
`jackd -d alsa -r 44100 -P hw:2`